# How to make PivotChart with line breaks

Tags: excel, plot, line, pivot-table, break

I have data like the following:

```
x   y   f
1   1   1.2
1   2   1.4
1   3   1.6
3   1   3.2
3   2   3.4
3   3   3.6
5   1   5.2
5   2   5.4
5   3   5.6
```

If you insert a pivot chart, you can plot `f` vs `x` and `y` using a line chart, and the plot has two stacked x-axes where the lower x-axes values are `1` `3` `5` corresponding to x, and the upper x-axes has values `1` `2` `3` for each value of the lower x-axes, representing x = 1 and y = 1 2 3, then x = 2 and y = 1 2 3, and x = 3 and y = 1 2 3.  The plot should show a single continuous line from left to right.  What I would like is for the line to break when `x` changes values, so there are three short lines showing the influence of `y` for constant values of `x`.

This [link](https://superuser.com/questions/775321/how-to-force-time-series-in-pivot-chart-force-break-in-line) makes a chart similar to what I'm describing in the answer.  In terms of that figure, what I want is for the link to break every time the year changes.  But the answer they have, and discussion doesn't get what I'm looking for.  The only approach that I can think of is to modify the PivotTable data by hand and add a row at the location the data breaks.  I tried to do something like that at work, but before modifying the table, I copied the table as values to a separate location.  With the new data table, I was not able to create the plot with two x axis.  If I created the plot, I could put a second value in when y = 3, and for f have NA(), which should create the break in the proper location.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  I have multiple fs, like f1, f2, f3, but I don't think that is important (is it?).  So, how did you get the line to break like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something that looks like:

[image: SO33451676 first example]

Select each of the second and subsequent y `1` values (individually):

[image: SO33451676 second example]

and Format Data Point..., Line, No line.

(BTW IMO better suited to Super User.)

Comment: This is my first excel question, I usually stick to R, java, and C.  Can I move the question or does the moderator move it?  When you say select each of the y 1 values, are you referring to the x axis values, or the points in the chart, or values in the table?  Can you add a figure to clarify?  Or, add little arrows to the figure above to point to what is being selected.  And, is format data point on the ribbon or right click menu?

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional figure, it is very clear.

Comment: A few years late - I wonder why Excel doesn't do this automatically? It's an odd workaround that we have to tweak if we re-do the graphs/data.  Thanks for this answer, it's simple and quick enough